# Is Firebase pod a requirement for using Crashlytics on iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

While trying to use Crashlytics on iOS, I am unable to send crash reports without including the Firebase pod (to configure FirebaseApp).

I don't wish to capture Analytics using Firebase. Is there a way to avoid including the Firebase cocoapod altogether or at the least disable the analytics data from being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this set of instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup?authuser=0#frameworks) should allow you to onboard without CocoaPods. However, if you want to use Firebase without Analytics, you would have to migrate from Fabric to Firebase, and forgo the Analytics SDK integration. Specifically for the migration flow the Google Analytics SDK is not necessary to use just Crashlytics.

Comment: I would want to use CocoaPods. Just that I don't want a whole lot of other frameworks accompanying the Fabric & Crashlytics pods. But, seems Firebase/Analytics is bare minimum required for initializing the Crashlytics module. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer with the correct information.

Comment: So to be clear, if I want to avoid the Firebase/Analytics pod from being included, I should start with Fabric and then migrate to Firebase and not start with Firebase directly?

Comment: Yep, as of right now, the Analytics framework is integrated with Crashlytics when onboarding a Firebase app. However, this is not the case if you're migrating from Fabric to Firebase. More simply, you can follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection) if you just want to stop Analytics data from reporting to your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. I was looking for this information.